# Route IP Traffic using nmcli / Centos 7

Tags: centos7, ip-routing

trying to create reroute from network 10.0.0.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24
nave a vps on VM , with 2 nics one connected to 10.x net with IP 10.0.0.3 (NAT) and other to 192.x with IP 192.168.0.3 (host only)

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno16777728: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:15:83:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.3/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eno16777728
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe15:838b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno33554952: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:15:83:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eno33554952
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe15:8395/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

using nmcli

```
nmcli connection modify "eno16777728" +ipv4.routes "192.168.0.0/24 10.0.0.3"
nmcli connection modify "eno33554952" +ipv4.routes "10.0.0.0/24 192.168.0.3"
nmcli connection reload
nmcli connection up eno16777728
nmcli connection up eno33554952
```

netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno16777728
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno16777728
192.168.0.0     10.0.0.3        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eno16777728
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno33554952
```

from an other vps from 10.x net pinging 192.x

ping 192.168.0.3

```
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.24 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.24 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.24 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

what I'm doing wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done nothing wrong, everything look ok ,, but look at your ping result, did u have some 192.168.0.24 gateway or something ?  if not I think something wrong with your eno33554952 interface, check VM configuration.